# How to see the indicators only for apps in current workspace?

Tags: icons, indicator, workspaces, gnome-classic, taskbar

This worked fine in 11.10, but today I upgraded to 12.10 and I can't remember what I had to do to get this to work correctly. What I want is:

When in a workspace, the only icons in the taskbar should be for applications that are running in the current workspace. What I see now are all application icons regardless of the workspace they are running in.

I am using Gnome Classic since I have a VPN client that only shows it's status in the system tray from Gnome Classic.

Comment: Are you talking about the *indicators* icons? If not, I should undo my edit. Also, could you add a screen-shoot? You can upload it in [Imgur](http://imgur.com/) and link it into your question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by _indicators_ icons. I'm talking about the application icons in the taskbar at the bottom of the workspace. If you look at [this image of the taskbar](https://www.dropbox.com/s/43rhzirirb7rg65/taskbar_capture.png) you'll see:

"Overview - Python v2.." This is from a Konqueror in Workspace 2
Terminal - from Workspace 1
Firefox - Bug... - from Workspace 3
Terminal/Python Shell/gedit of dhcpd_config.py - from Workspace 4
rdesktop - from Workspace 1 again

In 11.10 I set something so the icons were for apps in the current workspace only.

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, the solution to a different problem I was having (workspace names in the taskbar) ended up solving this as well. The solution is to use metacity instead of compiz. When I do that I only see the applications for each workspace in their respective workspaces (or viewports...).